# ServiceStack Metadata Redirect behind a Azure App Gateway not working

Tags: servicestack

My api is hosted on Azure as an App Service with an Azure App Gateway in front of that.

I have set the webhosturl in my startup and that is working as when I view the metadata page, i see the links pointing to the correct location.  And those links work. However when I navigate to the base url for my api, it redirects me to the app service url.

Here is a snippet of my startup...

```
        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            WebHostUrl = "https://api-dev.hsawaknow.net/link/",
            DefaultRedirectPath = "/metadata",
            DebugMode = AppSettings.Get(nameof(HostConfig.DebugMode), false)
        });
```

Please see the links below and see the differences.

https://api-dev.hsawaknow.net/link/metadata

vs

https://api-dev.hsawaknow.net/link/

You will get an https error as I am using a self signed cert, until I get this figured out.  I have seen other posts that say to make this change and that it works, but not for me.

Please help!

Comment: I even overrode the ResolveAbsoluteUrl setting it to point to the WebHostUrl and the metadata page is still not getting redirected to correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this figured out.  There were a couple things that I had to do.

First thing I had to do was setup the forwarded headers middleware to recognize and process the correct headers coming from the Azure Application Gateway.

```
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHostHeaderName = "X-ORIGINAL-HOST";
            options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor;
        });
```

This allowed my site to work with links to the correct pages without setting the WebHostUrl.  The only caveat about using the Azure App Gateway is that it uses X-ORIGINAL-HOST instead of the standard X-FORWARDED-HOST.

Next, I had to set the DefaultRedirectPath on the HostConfig dynamically based on settings in appsettings.json.  In the case of the Azure App Gateway, my public url was https://api-dev.hsawaknow.net/link/, I had to set the redirect to /link/metadata, instead of just metadata, because of how the host header was getting set in the previous step.

It took a few tries, but this configuration works well, when hosting on Azure App Services fronted with an Azure Application Gateway.

Kudos to the [mythz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz) for the quick response, which pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the [Request Logger](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-logger) so you can see what requests ServiceStack receives.

Does it work when not specifying a WebHostUrl?